# SailsJS deployment on azure is not stable

Tags: azure, sails.js, azure-redis-cache

I am using Redis for session management on SailsJS. I am facing two issues frequently on Azure:

1. user config hook took too much time to load. I get this error quite often.
2. Redis connection keeps on dropping. I am using node_redis to connect to azure redis and following is my redis configuration:

   redisConfig : {
   host: 'XXXXXX.redis.cache.windows.net',
   port: 6380,
   ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
   db: 2,
   tls: {servername: 'XXXXX.redis.cache.windows.net'},
   retry_unfulfilled_commands: true,
   enable_offline_queue: true,
   auth_pass: '',
   retry_strategy: function (options) {
     if (options.error && options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
       // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with a individual error
       return new Error('The server refused the connection');
     }
     if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 5) {
       // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands with a individual error
       return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
     }
     if (options.times_connected > 20) {
       // End reconnecting with built in error
       return new Error('Retry count exceeded 10');
     }
     // reconnect after
     return Math.max(options.attempt * 300, 5000);
   }
   }

Many times I am not able to access this Redis but still I don't get any error prompted by the app for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add hookTimeout:120000 in the .sailsrc file.This worked to inc the timeout for user config loading. Adding this in production or development config files was not helping as prod/dev env vars are not available when userconfig hook timeout is set.